# Is there way to determine order of calls to methods of a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Having class with 20 methods that being called in unknown order is there way to determine which method was called last?
I understand that I can put some `print` in each and determine it by myself.

But are there some built-ins for this?
Something like `dis` but showing method names

Comment: Can you show some exemplary code? What calls this methods?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... i.e why does the order matter? what happens when one isn't called at all?

Comment: @slhck, I seek for general approach. Script being called from command-line. It consists of one Class with 20  methods.

Comment: @Sayse, I have variables that being filled during execution and I want to get last point of execution so I could be sure that variable which I need is completely filled with data

Comment: Would it not be safer to just call one method that calls the other 20? or add method 21 - `check_ready`?

Comment: I'm wondering maybe there is something like `dis`  that will show actual methods names

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to override [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) and check if the requested attribute is a callable or not, if yes, save its name somewhere:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._last_called = None

    def method1(self):
        pass

    def method2(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        val = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        if callable(val):
            self._last_called = attr
        return val
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a._last_called
>>> a.method1()
>>> a._last_called
'method1'
>>> a.method2()
>>> a._last_called
'method2'
```

If you don't want to modify the actual class you can create a decorator and then apply it to any class:

```
def save_last_called_method(cls):
    original_getattribute = cls.__getattribute__

    def new_getattribute(ins, attr):
        val = original_getattribute(ins, attr)
        if callable(val):
            ins._last_called = attr
        return val

    cls.__getattribute__ = new_getattribute

    return cls

@save_last_called_method
class A(object):

    def method1(self):
        pass

    def method2(self):
        pass


@save_last_called_method
class B(object):

    def method3(self):
        pass

a = A()
a.method1()
print a._last_called
a.method2()
print a._last_called
b = B()
b.method3()
print b._last_called
print a._last_called
```

**Output:**

```
method1
method2
method3
```

Comment: Have I misread the question? o.O

Comment: I just want to know which one was called last. Found `inspect` module, seems like this was what I need. Also I do not have an option of overriding any behaviour of this class or modifying it

Comment: @micgeronimo That's exactly what the above code is doing.

Comment: @micgeronimo Then you're making it a XY problem with self made restrictions. There's no magic built-in which will allow you to know the last called method if that's what you wanted to know.  In this solution I didn't even import anything.

Comment: @micgeronimo Do share your built-ins solution with us, I will learn something new then.

Comment: `print inspect.stack()[0][3]` in each method

Comment: @micgeronimo "Also I do not have an option of overriding any behaviour of this class or **modifying** it".